# get git submodule path, based on url

Tags: git

I am interested in the path of a particular submodule which URL is known.

```
[submodule "foo"]
  path = app/foo
  url = https://my-known-url
  branch = main
```

I can kind of get the path using hacky grep commands, but I am not confident that this won't break one day.

```bash
cat .gitmodules | grep -B 1 -A 1 my-known-url | grep path | cut -d'=' -f 2 | xargs
```

I have also tried to use `git config --file .gitmodules ...` without success. One caveat is that this has to work with azure devops ssh origins starting with `git@ssh.dev.azure.com:v3`. For example, `--get-urlmatch` doesn't seem to like that format.

Comment: "I have also tried to use git config --file .gitmodules ... without success." What did you try? Why didn't it work? That seems a pretty promising direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will do it:

```
#!/bin/bash

git config --file .gitmodules --list |
  awk -vURL="$1" -F= '$2 == URL {print $1}' |
  sed 's/\.url$/.path/' |
  xargs -IKEY git config --file .gitmodules --get KEY
```

Answer (score 1):

Shell script that loops over URLs, finds the one and prints the corresponding `.path`:

```bash
#! /bin/sh
set -e
find_url="$1"

git config -f .gitmodules --get-regexp '^submodule\..*\.url$' |
while read name url; do
    if [ "$url" = "$find_url" ]; then
        path_key="`echo $name | sed s/\.url$/.path/`"
        git config -f .gitmodules --get "$path_key"
        break
    fi
done
```